# Constraints on number of subflows?

Tags: corda

(Asking on behalf of a client.)  In Corda is there any issue with a flow initiating many (even hundreds) of subflows, for example updating many participants from a single flow?  If not, what is considered the best practice when one main transaction needs to trigger many other transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Initiating many subflows within a flow is not an issue and will not affect performance.

Deciding whether to use many subflows or keep everything in a single flow is a matter of personal preference and readability.